# How to convert rows of DataFrame to a List/Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
id  | type  | count
-------------------
1   | A     | 2 
2   | B     | 4
```

I want to pass each row of this `df` as the input of the function `saveObj`.

```
df.foreach( row => {
  val list = List("id" -> row.get(0),"type" -> row.get(1))
  saveObj(list)
})
```

Inside `saveObj` I want to access `list` values as follows: `list("id")`, `list("type")`.

How can I avoid using indices of columns?: `row.get(0)`or `row.get(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getAs` which expects a column name. By first creating a list of column names you're interested in - you can map them to the desired list of tuples:

```
// can also use df.columns.toList to get ALL columns
val columns = List("id", "type") 

df.foreach(row => {
  saveObj(columns.map(name => name -> row.getAs[Any](name)))
})
```

Alternatively, you can take advantage of `Row.apply` by using pattern matching - but in this case still require knowing the order of columns in the `Row` and repeating the column names:

```
df.foreach(_ match {
  case Row(id: Any, typ: Any, _) => saveObj(List("id" -> id, "type" -> typ))
})
```

Comment: `df.getAs[Something]` is so useful not sure why it repeatedly slips the memory banks. Oh actually what I just typed is different - but more aligned with my current need